# express path issues when using same logic on diffrent paths

Tags: express

id path is working (I get the result from the json), but even though pokeName uses the same logic, I dont get any data from it. What have we missed?

JSON: https://github.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/blob/master/pokedex.json

```
const Pokemons = mongoose.model('Pokemons', {
  id: Number,
  name: String,
  type: Array,
})
_____

app.get('/pokemons', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!allPokemons) {
      res.status(404).send('No data to show')
    } else {
      res.json(allPokemons.pokemon) /*[1].name*/
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Not found' })
  }
})

_____

app.get('/pokemons/id/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const pokemon = allPokemons.pokemon.find((item) => item.id === +id)
  try {
    if (!pokemon) {
      res.status(404).send('No pokemon found with this ID')
    } else {
      res.json(pokemon)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Not found' })
  }
})

_____ 

app.get('/pokemons/name/:pokeName', async (req, res) => {
  const { pokeName } = req.params
  const pokemon = allPokemons.pokemon.find((item) => item.name === +pokeName)
  try {
    if (!pokemon) {
      res.status(404).send('No pokemon found with this name')
    } else {
      res.json(pokemon)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Not found' })
  }
})
```

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert the name to a number (presumably because `id` *is* a number, and you copied its code):

```
item.name === +pokeName
```

But it's not, so this will result in a `NaN`. Remove the `+`:

```
item.name === pokeName
```